# Как в laravel передать массив?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Как передать массив в view и там его перебрать foreach ?

Контроллер

```
public function index(){
    return view('pages/menu');
}

public function test(Request $request){
    $test = Menu::find($request['id']);
        return $test;
    }
```

Route

```
Route::get('/menu', 'MenuController@index')->name('menu.index');
Route::post('/menu-test', 'MenuController@test')->name('menu.test');
```

View

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

<div id="test"></div>
<div class="test">Принять</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('click', '.test', function() {
           var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
           var id = 8;
                 $.ajax({
                    url: '{{route('menu.test')}}',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, id,},
                    dataType: 'HTML',
                    success: function (data) { 
                        $('#test').html(data);
                    }
                }); 
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Или только на стороне контроллера создавать к примеру html разметку с данными и передавать во view ? К примеру return $html = '<p>'.$test->name.'</p>'

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятен вопрос, но предположу что речь об этом.

```
public function test(Request $request){
    $test = Menu::find($request['id']);
    return view('pages.menu', ['test' => $test]);
}
```

И зачем вам перебор если у вас в переменной `$test` находится 1 сущность?
В шаблоне:

```
<p>{{ $test->name }}</p>
```

и так далее.
Поправьте меня если вы другое имели ввиду

Comment: Получение записи из базы идет через запрос ajax при клике на кнопку, а в шаблоне если вписать сразу <p>{{ $test->name }}</p> то ошика Undefined variable: test

Comment: @Федотов если вы делаете запрос аяксом то и возвращать должны json и уже через js подставлять значения